# CSS to place picture box in my dialog box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a message box with a square image on the left of the dialog box. I'll get close by trying different examples online, then try something else and my efforts start to fall apart because I just can't get a good feel for this.

The only way I can think to do this is with a table, but it seems like nobody uses tables anymore for things like this. Are `<DIV>` tags the best choice? `<SPAN>`?

```
<div class="alert" id="sfAlert">
  <div class="picturebox"></div>
  <div class="messagebox">
    <span class="button" id="sfClose">&times;</span>
    <h2><div class="messagetext" id="sfMsg1">Intro Text 1</div></h2>
    <div class="messagetext" id="sfMsg2">Intro Text 2</div><hr/>
    <small><div class="messagetext" id="sfMsg3">Intro Text 2</div></small>
  </div>
```

It would also be nice to find a way to specify that whatever is the container for the top message `sfMsg1` should be in Large, Bold characters. I've done this by wrapping the `<div>` tag with the `<h2>` element, but I don't know if that is the recommended technique.

https://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/sjvmkf9n/23/

Comment: Do you have a picture or already implemented example of what you want your content to look like? It's hard to understand how your current code is falling short of your desired expectations.

Comment: @TylerH - it would be something with work's logo. I could get fired for putting that out here.

Comment: I doubt it, but also you can just mock up something with a placeholder image instead, or use MS Paint, etc. As of now it looks like your code already is laid out as you want.

Comment: @TylerH - there is a mock image in the jsfiddle link.

Comment: @TylerH - something like this: https://i.imgur.com/JLocMNQ.png (my photoshop skills are not in question here, I hope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an image multiple ways, if you do not care about its relation with its siblings, one way would be to use `position: absolute`.

When you use `position: absolute` the element will be positioned in relation with its closest **positioned** ancestor [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), it seems like you want the image to be near the top-left corner of the alert, so I gave that element a `position: relative` attribute.

To have bigger, bold, font on the header, you can use `font-size` and `font-weight`.

```css
#sfAlert {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 30px;
}

.picturebox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif');
  background-size: contain;
}

#sfMsg1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

#small-message-text {
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert" id="sfAlert">
  <div class="picturebox"></div>
  <div class="messagebox">
    <span class="button" id="sfClose">&times;</span>
    <div class="messagetext" id="sfMsg1">Intro Text 1</div>
    <div class="messagetext" id="sfMsg2">Intro Text 2</div>
    <hr/>
    <small><div class="messagetext" id="sfMsg3">Intro Text 2</div></small>
    <div id="small-message-text">Intro Text 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting the text for the `sfMsg1` to work, but `font-size: -2em;` doesn't work to replace the `<small>` tag.

Comment: Small would be something like `font-size: 0.7em` you can also use other units like `font-size: 10px;`

Comment: I added a line for smaller text without `<small>`, on Firefox `0.85em` is pretty close. I guess it also depends on the inherited font, not sure how precise you need it to be.

Comment: Using your example, I finally had a chance to come in and finish it up. Thanks. Here's my end result: https://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/sjvmkf9n/41/